# Flutter FocusNode onKeyEvent detect multiple keys

Tags: flutter

Using this for Flutter Desktop. I used to use `onKey` of `FocusNode`. The doc says it will be deprecated:

```
  /// To receive key events that focuses on this node, pass a listener to `onKeyEvent`.
  /// The `onKey` is a legacy API based on [RawKeyEvent] and will be deprecated
  /// in the future.
```

This is how I used `onKey` for detecting shift + enter:

```
FocusNode(          
    onKey: (node, event)
    {
        if (event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter))
        {
            if (event.isShiftPressed)
                return KeyEventResult.ignored;

            sendAction();
            return KeyEventResult.handled;
        }

        return KeyEventResult.ignored;
    },
```

How do you detect multiple keys being pressed at the same time with `onKeyEvent`?

Edit: I'm looking for a way to detect multiple keys being pressed WITHOUT the legacy approach. The event parameter in `onKeyEvent` is not
`RawKeyEvent` type, therefore `isKeyPressed()` is not available there. The only thing available is `event.logicalKey.keyLabel` which can't be used for multiple key detection.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question. Are you asking how to detect keys without a legacy approach?

Comment: Multiple keys without legacy approach. `isKeyPressed()` is not available in `onKeyEvent`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle the shortcuts **Flutter** has `Shortcut` widget. To start using it you have to specify:

- **Intent** - describes that shortcut intent triggered
- **Action** - describes action on triggered Intent

Let's create an intent class

```
class NewLineIntent extends Intent {
  const NewLineIntent();
}
```

Add it to your widget and specify the conditions:

```
static const newLine = SingleActivator(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter, shift: true);
```

Finally, build a widget:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Shortcuts(
      shortcuts: const {
        newLine: NewLineIntent()
      },
      child: Actions(
        actions: {
          NewLineIntent: CallbackAction<NewLineIntent>(
            onInvoke: (NewLineIntent intent) {
              print('New line');
            },
          )
        },
        child: Focus(
          autofocus: true,
          child: ... ,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And when your widget will appear on the screen and you press `Shift` + `Enter` your shortcut will be triggered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm gonna mark it as solved. However since the old solution was done via `onKey` I was under the impression that the new solution should also be done via `onKeyEvent`, not a completely different approach. Again thanks for the effort!

Comment: When I investigated your question I also tried to do this with the new approach but the main issue is that you can't catch keys when a combination of keys is pressed and I continue with Shortuct approach

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of `onKeyEvent` is indeed quite strange because it doesn't allow to check for modifier keys while pressing another key. It just supports handling of one key at a time. So if you want to check for multiple keys pressed, you can use `HardwareKeyboard` to check for another key when pressing enter. Like this:

```
FocusNode(
  onKeyEvent: (node, event) {
    final enterPressedWithShift = event is KeyDownEvent &&
        event.physicalKey == PhysicalKeyboardKey.enter &&
        HardwareKeyboard.instance.physicalKeysPressed.any(
          (key) => <PhysicalKeyboardKey>{
            PhysicalKeyboardKey.shiftLeft,
            PhysicalKeyboardKey.shiftRight,
          }.contains(key),
        );

    if (enterPressedWithShift) {
      // Do something
      return KeyEventResult.handled;
    } else {
      return KeyEventResult.ignored;
    }
  },
);
```